# how to run sql scripts on sql azure db when deploying to azure website

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have a pre-existing sql-azure db and an azure-website setup which is automatically deployed with each bitbucket push.  Now I would like to run some .sql scripts I have in a specific folder in a specific order with each deploy as we make changes to the db each release. How would I go about doing this in Azure?

I've read this guide: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script, and I understand that there's a `deploy.cmd` file generated when running `azure-cli` command that I need to modify. Just wondering what to add in there for sql changes. I already have a connection string for the sql azure db containing the username and password that I can use. Just need to know how I can actually execute these scripts against the sql azure db. Specifically following steps:

1. Connect to sql azure db using the connection string
2. Look in a specified folder for sql scripts and:
3. Run the sql scripts in a specific order (they start with numbers e.g.: 015script.sql, 016script.sql)
4. Some sort of error output if something failed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can leverage node.js scripts and defined into the `scripts` section in the `package.json`, and config the custom npm script into the `deploy.cmd` file, then the deployment task will call the custom script.

Please try the following steps:

1. Create a file `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd` by `azure-cli` command `azure site deploymentscript --node --sitePath nodejs`
2. create a node.js script in your application which will can handle sql operations, e.g.

   `var sql = require('mssql');
   var config = {
       user: '<user>',
       password: '<pwd>',
       server: '<database_server>.database.windows.net', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance 
       database: '<databasename>',
       options: {
           encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
       }
   }
   var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
       var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request(); 
       request.query("insert into dbo.todoitem (text) values ('test string')", function(err, recordset) {
           // ... error checks 
           console.log(err);
           console.dir(recordset);
           process.exit();
       });
   });
   connection.on('error', function(err) {
       // ... error handler 
   });`
3. Modify the `package.json`, add the `mssql` module and config the custom scripts:

   `{
     "engines": {
       "node": "5.9.1"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "mssql": "^3.3.0"
     },
     "devDependencies": {},
     "scripts": {
       "customscript": "node connection.js"
     },
   }`
4. Modify the `deploy.cmd` to add the step to call the `npm run customscript` command during the Azure deployment task, in the original `deploy.cmd` file, you can find the sentence to install node.js modules:

   `:: 3. Install npm packages
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
     pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
     call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
     popd
   )`

   You can directly add the script under it:

   `echo npm customscript
   call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run customscript`
5. Then deploy your application to Azure via Git, it will run the custom npm script during the deployment task, and will query your SQL.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so turns out you can just use SqlCmd directly in deploy.cmd to do this. Following are the steps ([source](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38419111245/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart3/#.V40AeLgrKUk)):

1. install npm on your machine
2. run the following command `npm install azure-cli -g`
3. for mvc4 web application run : `azure site deploymentscript --aspWAP mvc4\Mvc4WebApplication\Mvc4WebApplication.csproj -s Mvc4\Mvc4WebApplication.sln`
4. This will create .deployment and deploy.cmd files. Add these to the root of your repository.

I couldn't really find a good source for below, and I just got lucky when testing this out on Kudu cmd tool:

Modify deploy.cmd section under `Deployment` section add something like the following:

```
set dbName=mydb
set sqlRunner=sqlcmd
set dbServer=tcp:myorg.database.windows.net,1433
set currentdir=%cd%
set username=myusername
set password=mypassword

for %%F IN ("%currentdir%\DBScripts\05.Changes\*.sql") do (
    @echo %%F
    %sqlRunner% -S "%dbServer%"  -U %username% -P %password% -d %dbName% -i "%%F" -b
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR
)
```

The Key here is availability of `sqlcmd`. This is what I was looking for. You can actually test all of this out from within Kudu Cmd Tool.